# How to customize C++ compiler error message(s) in MSBuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Is it possible to influence how exactly MSBuild formats and reports output of CL.EXE that is run as part of building a C++ project?

They actually differ when run from command-line and from Visual Studio:

```
Command-line:  file(line): error message [project]
Visual Studio: file(line): error message
```

It seems like a minor detail, however I really, really need to display the [project] also from inside Visual Studio builds as I'm triggering builds of prerequisites and do not want to mix their errors with errors of the parent project.

I've tried faking $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) and observing whichever properties are being passed to MSBuild but to no avail and cannot get the command-line error message style into VS. One way of forcing it is using an <Exec> task instead of <MSBuild> but spawning a separate build process is undesirable in almost every way imaginable. Is there any way to convince it peacefully? Even when $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) is overridden to true or false, it doesn't seem to affect the style of the error output. Strange. Maybe Visual Studio intercepts and reformats the message?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possibly VS uses a custom logger - not sure if it possible to replace it though

Comment: Leads me to that conclusion too. I wish there was a way to extend it.

Comment: One possible 'poor man's' approach would be to enable logging to file in VS, then after your build completes invoke a custom task which parses the logfile and fetches errors/project build start events, then output them again using LogError but with the project info appended

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild provides very good extensibility. Place any *.targets file under `$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\$(Platform)\ImportBefore\` with custom targets to be loaded before the standard processing.

1. Create a file named `custom.cpp.win32.targets` under:

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Win32\ImportBefore\
2. Copy the following into `custom.cpp.win32.targets`. This will print the full path of the project before calling cl.exe:

   ```
   <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <BeforeClCompileTargets>
        BeforeClCompileCustom;
      $(BeforeClCompileTargets);
     </BeforeClCompileTargets> 
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="BeforeClCompileCustom">
       <Message Importance="high" 
                Text="Building '$(ProjectName)' - $(Platform)|$(Configuration) [$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)]" />
   </Target>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I would like to customize the actual output of cl.exe so that any error shown in Error window in VS also includes the project of origin just as the command-line version of MSBuild seems to do. Would you know how to customize how output of cl.exe (warnings/errors) is presented by MSBuild (when run from inside VS)?

Comment: VS `Error List` pane is designed for that. Clicking on the error in the output pane will also open the source file. I don't see any reason to change that behaviour. It's fine as it is.

Comment: Ok, let me elaborate. If you run a <MSBuild> task as part of your project compilation, if will show up under the name of the project that ran it, regardless whether you are actually compiling completely different project file (because you need it as a prerequisite and it's not part of your solution) or not. The reason to change the error output is for me adding the information that the error encountered is in fact in a different project.  Although clicking on it does indeed navigate to the source file, without clicking, there is no way to know which project is responsible ('Parent' is shown).

Comment: And to answer a possible follow-up question "Why don't I simply use project-to-project references":  We have well over 300 projects participating in our build so having them all together, in one solution, is simply chaos that must not grow any further. I wrote a build script that does correctly understand and build their dependencies even if they are in different solutions and the last mile is only that Visual Studio reports any errors encountered as being in the project that *triggered* the pre-requisite <MSBuild> which is confusing to developers. But adding a simple "in project XXX"...